# In Windows 10 file is saved without permission and is visible only to the program that saved it

Tags: windows-10, permissions, uac

In Windows 10 different software behaves differently when I am trying to save files to the C:\ root directory. Some simply fail/refuse, saying I have no permission (MS Word, console `copy` command etc.), others let me do that after I confirm my administrator permissions through UAC. Such behavior is *not* a problem I am trying to solve. There seems to be the third kind of software which behaves rather strange. So far I have only observed such behavior with [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com), but I don't think it's IrfanView-specific.

This is what IrfanView does when asked to save a file in C:. It doesn't ask for administrator permission, and neither it fails. It looks like it saves the file to C:\ silently and without a question. However, such files can only be seen in IrfanView: they are invisible for FileExplorer or for `dir /a`, but if I run IrfanView first and select its "Open" menu command, the files are there, can be opened, edited, saved again, moved, copied etc.

So, what's happening? Is it some sort of a compatibility thing for software that is too dumb to ask for permissions? What does Windows 10 really do with those files?

Comment: It's probably [UAC virtualisation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681). We probably have a duplicate question somewhere. I might dig it up when I get back to a computer.

Comment: see also from TechNet: "For the purposes of this virtualization, Windows Vista treats a process as legacy if it’s 32-bit (versus 64-bit), is not running with administrative rights, and does not have a manifest file indicating that it was written for Windows Vista." most modern programs have a newer manifest by default. afaik win10 behaves the same as Vista here.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the case. The files actually went to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore.